# Unit Testing Db4oTool Instrumentation (Collections)

Tags: db4o

I am using the db4oTool to instrument my classes for transparent activation/persistence.
I am using the -ta and -collections switches.

I know how to check that the classes themselves are being properly instrumented by the following test.

```
Assert.IsTrue(typeof(IActivatable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Machine)), "Machine class not instrumented");
```

Reference: [http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/net35/reference/Content/basics/transparentpersistence/ta_enhanced_example.htm](http://Db4o%20Reference)

However I do not know how to check that my collections are being instrumented correctly.

Given the following machine class:

```
public class Machine : DomainBase
    {
        private string _machineId;

        public string MachineId
        {
            get { return _machineId; }
            set { _machineId = value; }
        }


        public IList<EnergyTag> EnergyTags { get; set; }

        public void AddEnergyTag(EnergyTag energyTag)
        {
            if (energyTag.Machine == null)
                energyTag.Machine = this;
            if (EnergyTags == null)
                EnergyTags = new List<EnergyTag>();
            EnergyTags.Add(energyTag);
        }

    }
```

How would I test that the EnergyTags collection was properly instrumented?

**Edit:**

Solution:

```
var machine = new Machine();                                                        
Assert.IsTrue(machine.EnergyTags.GetType().Equals(typeof(ActivatableList<EnergyTag>)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the concrete type of *EnergyTags*:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Item
{
    private IList<Item> l = new List<Item>();

    public IList<Item> Items
    {
        get { return l; }

        set { l = value; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", new Item().Items.GetType().FullName);
    }   
}
```

Will output something like:

*Type: Db4objects.Db4o.Collections.ActivatableList`1[[Item, ActivatableCollections, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]*

So you can either check by name (if you don't have a reference to db4o assemblies in your model) or by type otherwise.

Keep in mind that this name (ActivatableList) is an implementation detail and may change in future db4o releases.

Best

Comment: Thanks Vagaus, that got me where I needed to be.  Final solution is appended to my original question.